# Append JSON object to encrypted text file PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, encryption

I am typically transferring JSON objects from JavaScript and saving them with PHP.

I then append them to a specific text file like this:

```
        $theFile = fopen("Data/" . FQ . ".txt", "a+");
        fwrite($theFile, $data.PHP_EOL);
        fclose($theFile);
```

Can I add code to save this information as an **encrypted** text file?

Ideally, I want:

- All the files on my server to be encrypted
- A secret key that is stored on my local computer

To decipher, I would:

- Transfer data from server to local computer
- Use my local secret key to decipher

I want this so that if my server is compromised, all data is gibberish without the secret key (which is **NOT** stored on the server anywhere).

Comment: Yes, you can add code to do that.  But yes/no questions aren't that useful.  If your question is *how* you go about doing that, then your question is too broad for StackOverflow.  I recommend you attempt to solve the problem yourself first and edit your question to include a more specific problem.

Comment: What resources can you recommend so that I can get more specific? I have heard of things like AES and SHA, but I have no idea where to begin really.

Comment: AES is an encryption algorithm and would be an appropriate choice for this situation.  The SHA family of algorithms are hashing algorithms and don't really have anything to do with encryption.  I would begin by looking at the `openssl_encrypt` function in PHP, and view the code examples in [this repository](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples).

Comment: So I think I am following along with the general idea of how to encrypt the information, but it looks like they are storing the keys to decrypt the content WITHIN the encrypted content. I would like to avoid that, and never decrypt the content on my server anywhere. I would like it to be encrypted without any trace of the key on my server; does that make sense?

Comment: You are mistaken - the key is passed in to the function as an argument.  It isn't stored with the data in any way.  That would entirely defeat the point of encrypting.

Comment: But you are saying to pass the key into the argument, which means it has to reference a key, which means the key is somewhere on the server, right?

Comment: No, use the code to encrypt locally and then transmit to the server for storage.  The code we are discussing should execute on your local device.

Comment: But I want to encrypt information that keeps changing based on user inputs. Right now, for each "trial", I append a new line to save the user input. I want to keep that model, but the new line is encrypted using the same key to an encrypted file.

Also, the file does not exist until a user enters my website, so I do not know if I can create the files first locally and then transfer to server. Although perhaps I could encrypt the entire folder first and each new file is encrypted the same way?

Thanks for trying to help a newbie.

Comment: So you want the server to be able to add encrypted information to the file but not be able to decrypt that information?

Comment: If your PHP application needs to append data to an encrypted file, it will need to decrypt the file first, right?

Comment: Luke - that was my original question and idea. I want everything encrypted on my server, but only capable of being decrypted locally with a key stored on my local computer. That may not be possible. Maybe a better / more realistic question is (if that is impossible, as Don't Panic is suggesting): What is the best way to store the key on my server?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want a symmetric encryption algorithm, such as AES.  It turns out that there is a decent JavaScript implementation of it as part of Forge.

https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#aes

You'll want to use CBC mode to encrypt the payload and send it to your server.

If you're dead set on keeping this in a text file, you'll have to base64-encode this binary data.  **Do this server-side.**  Your client code shouldn't need to know or care how your server is actually storing the data.  Plus, you'll save yourself 33% bandwidth, and some client-side CPU.

As a bonus to the base64-encoding, you'll be able to line-delimit the records in your text file.

When you return the data to your client, you should decode the base64 and send them the binary encrypted data.  The client will then decrypt it using the key that only it knows.

Comment: very interesting reply, is there a way to save this to my profile so I can quick access to it in the future?

Comment: @Mr-Programs There's a star icon next to the question.  You can mark it as a favorite that way.

Comment: i think the question is average low, i only liked your reply, but ill do so

Comment: its also worth mentioning that POST requests incur some sort of better security than lets say GET requests so they are harder to trace by default, is this only cause the payload isn't on the string or does this mean also other security features such as some sort of default encryption?

Comment: @Mr-Programs No, that's not true.  There is no real security difference between POST and GET requests.  You should use the verb for the operation at hand.  If you're GET-ing something, use GET.  If you're sending data to the server to create a new resource, use POST.  If you're sending data to a specific resource, use PUT.  To remove it, use DELETE.

Comment: POST is def more secure than GET, it is something so basic that its always taught in programming 101, here a link https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33837/get-vs-post-which-is-more-secure

Comment: @Mr-Programs Whomever told you that is wrong, and if you read the answer you linked to, you would understand why.  The issue with GET requests is logging.  There's nothing inherently insecure about GET on its own.  You might be interested to know that many server configurations also log POST request bodies.  It's a total myth that POST is somehow more secure, and you should stop perpetuating that myth.  Both are inherently insecure without proper transport encryption (HTTPS), or with poor handling of data on each end (insecure logging, etc.).

Comment: @Mr-Programs Let me put it another way... if we made up some arbitrary scale of security from 0 to 100, with 100 being the most secure... if an unencrypted GET request was a 5, an unencrypted POST request might be a 5.1.

Comment: no, because you can make a javascript that checks history urls, if you made a get request with a payload then ud be able to cross request this info out of some other site, while if you sent some payload with post a cross request forgery cant be done since the post payload would be only accessible to the x domain. this is one of the reasons, i was wondering if there were more i didnt know like some default ssl body payload light encryption

Comment: @Mr-Programs This is an API, the URLs won't be in the history.  As far as cross-domain GET requests, I suggest you read up on how CORS works so that you can understand how trivial it is to prevent cross-domain requests... if you even need/want to do that.  (Remember, that just because there's no pre-flight request doesn't mean you're not protected!)  Most APIs are built in such a way that they don't depend on cookie data or other stateful data.  Therefore, client-side applications on other domains aren't magically authorized anyway.

Comment: @Mr-Programs If you're using HTTPS, the whole request/response is encrypted end-to-end.